# Can't use 3rd level characters on atom

Tags: arch-linux, kde, keyboard, manjaro, atom-editor

Whenever I want to type any character that needs third level like "@" or "#" on atom or any other electron based application like discord. I have to use other applications like kate to write the character copy it and paste it where I need it, I have been using manjaro for a few months and it didn't happen until a week ago for some reason.

I am using manjaro 21.2.0 with KDE Plasma and the keyboard's layout is the Spanish (Windows) layout, I have tried using other layouts and configuring the 3rd level keys shortcut, but nothing of that worked, with it, I used to have problems with firefox too, but putting both alts as my 3rd level shortcut worked for it somehow.

I've searched for solutions everywhere, but they are nowhere, I hope you have the answer, it's very painful to not be able to access |@#[{ easily.

Comment: just to get this straight - your third level selector key is "Alt Gr", right?

Comment: By default it should be, but as I said I changed it to both alts and that works for firefox

Comment: Does alt gr then work in your electron/atom apps?

Comment: No, that's the problem

Comment: I haven't used a Spanisih keyboard since before electron was a thing, so I don't remember for sure, but isn't there a version of Spanish layout with "dead keys"? Can you try that one?

Comment: I have tried default, sun type 6/7, macintosh, windows, dead tilde, and no dead keys. None of them work.